# R ggplot2: plot min, avg, max and fill area between curves

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is of the form:

```
no  min     avg     max
1   0.000   42.565  30.681
2   50.292  60.203  74.392
3   65.029  73.392  81.939
...
```

I would like to plot curves of the minimum, average and maximum values and fill the area between the minimum and the average curve and the area between the average and the maximum curve (something similar to the chart below, without the dots). Is this possible with ggplot? Maybe with `geom_ribbon()`?

[image]

Comment: Yes, use `geom_ribbon`.

Comment: got a bad day, Roland? ;)

Comment: no, it was fine so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(no,ymin=min,ymax=max),color="yellow",alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(no,avg))
```